# Find how to sign in using conventional way of using userid/ password to sign into Jenkins if SSO configuration or SSO way of signing in doesn’t work

Tags: jenkins, single-sign-on, keycloak

We have self hosted keycloak and Jenkins and integrated Jenkins with keycloak for sso.

We are able to sign in successfully as well into Jenkins using sso

However what scares us is the incident where we were not able to sign in using Keycloak sso due to sso misconfiguration

We want to ensure we can sign in using normal user id and password during times when sso doesn’t work

How can we fall back to normal sign in while still using sso when it works

We tried to use Mixing Security Plugin to get multiply option to select multiply security realm which didnt work